# How can I use gtk_window_set_transient_for ()?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am using the library gtkmm. My code is almost perfect, I think because it compiles and I can execute it. But in the terminal when I clicked on open a file in my software that I made with gtkmm I can read this message :

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

So I looked for on this forum how can I solve it and I understood I have to use this method : gtk_window_set_transient_for().

Actually I have a Gtk::Window and a Gtk::FileChooserDialog. Can you put an example which use gtk_window_set_transient_for() ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: "My code is almost perfect" - That is a very bold statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gtk::FileChooserDialog` and other GTK+ dialogues are derived from `Gtk::Window`. `Gtk::Window` has the method `set_transient_for(Gtk::Window &parent);` which if not set gives you the message you have seen.

To fix this `set_transient_for(Gtk::Window &)` needs to be used. Note that this takes a reference and not a pointer. So you would use it something like this.

```
{
  Gtk::Window first_window;

  ...

  Gtk::FileChooserDialog file_dialog("Title");

  ...

  file_dialog.set_transient_for(first_window);

  ...
}
```

It is also possible to set the transient window for the dialog with the constructor. like so.

```
{
  Gtk::Window first_window;

  ...

  Gtk::FileChooserDialog file_dialog(first_window, "Title");

  ...
}
```

If `first_window` is a pointer the you would need to do something like so.

```
file_dialog.set_transient_for(*first_window);
```

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank you !